# Android NFC Unresolved reference: setNdefPushMessage

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc, ndef

I'm working on an Android application that's supposed to send text data from one phone to another via `NFC`. I've been referring to the official Android NFC documentation:
https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/nfc/nfc

In my code, I'm trying to use the setNdefPushMessage method as follows:

```kotlin
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter
...
private var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = null
...
nfcAdapter?.setNdefPushMessage(this, this)
```

However, I'm encountering an error, which is as follows:

```
Unresolved reference: setNdefPushMessage
```

I've searched the `android.nfc.NfcAdapter` library codes, but I couldn't find the `setNdefPushMessage` or `setNdefPushMessageCallback` method. Has this method been removed, or is this an Android Studio issue? Can someone suggest an alternative way to send and receive NFC data on Android?

I've already checked the Android NFC documentation and tried a few things, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

### Additional Information:

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636, built on September 15, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 12
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.intellij.marketplace (223.8836.56)
    com.github.copilot (1.2.5.2507)
    izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (2023.3.6)
    com.mallowigi (85.1.0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending NdefRecord via NFC but Receiving android.nfc.tech.IsoDep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070649/sending-ndefrecord-via-nfc-but-receiving-android-nfc-tech-isodep)

Comment: These methods were deprecated in API level 29 and removed from Android 10

Comment: @Andrew, I appreciate your input.

I'd like to point out that in this question user can indeed utilize the `setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback` method for this question. However, I've encountered an issue in Android Studio where it appears as though this method does not exist, and I'm seeking assistance with resolving this problem.

Comment: @Andrew, Is there any alternative method or API for transferring text data via NFC as these methods were deprecated in API level 29?